# How to sort a text file numerically?

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to sort a text file in numerical order, from largest at the top of the file, to lowest at the bottom of the file. Each line in the file only contains one number. I want to know how I can sort the text file every time run the code so that the numbers are always sorted. This is then used so I can then make a leaderboard.

```
    savefile.write("\n")
    savefile.write(User1)
    savefile.write(" Got a total score of ")
    savefile.write(Total1)
    savefile.close()
    savefile = open("Winnersnum.txt","a")
    savefile.write("\n")
    savefile.write(Total1)
    savefile.close()
```

All the numbers are saved in winnersnum.txt and if anyone could tell me how to sort it that would be great. (I know I can sort it using variables and reading but I don't want to have to make a bunch of lines to read with a bunch of variables)

Here is an example of the Winnersnum text file:
[Picture of file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uj8dr.png)

Comment: Please add an example of your Winnersum.txt file, thanks!

Comment: Typically, it's better to paste a short stretch of data like that right into the question, rather than linking to a screenshot. It saves the people helping you some alt-tabbing and typing.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all the values in a list, sort the list, and write them out, as such:

```
with open("winnersum.txt", "r") as txt:
    file = txt.read()

scores = file.split('\n') #converts to list
scores = [int(x) for x in scores] #converts strings to integers
scores.sort(reverse=True) # sorts results

with open("winnersum.txt", "w") as txt:
    for i in scores:
        txt.write(f"{i}\n")
```