# How to sort a text file numerically while having the number imbedded into other strings

Tags: python, sorting

Hi I'm looking for help with sorting my text file in numerical order, I have found [How to sort a text file numerically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62284908/how-to-sort-a-text-file-numerically) which shows me how to sort the numbers but in my text file I have the numbers in with other non numeric characters.

My text file might look like this:

```
Username1, 78 pts
Username2, 64 pts
Username3, 98 pts
Username4, 81 pts
Username5, 43 pts
Username6, 56 pts
```

*The usernames would be different those are just placeholders*

I have tried sorting with the numbers at the front of each line but since the answer linked above converts the entire line into integers I only get greeted with an error. If anyone knows how to sort all the whole line using just those numbers that would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks, Joe

Comment: Are all the lines of this exact structure (username-comma-space-number)?

Comment: This question "[How to sort a list of strings numerically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426108/how-to-sort-a-list-of-strings-numerically)" could be useful.

Comment: Yes they are all the same structure

Comment: If you are in linux, `sort -k 2 filename`

Comment: I'm not unfortunately, would that work on any python compiler though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

with open('./test.txt', 'r') as fh:
  lines = [l.rstrip() for l in fh.readlines()]

lines = [x.split() for x in lines]
lines.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
lines = [' '.join(x) for x in lines]

with open('./test.txt', 'w') as fh:
  fh.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

Sorted file:

```
Username5, 43 pts
Username6, 56 pts
Username2, 64 pts
Username1, 78 pts
Username4, 81 pts
Username3, 98 pts
```

Comment: Thank you. If I wanted to order it in descending order is there a way to do that?

Comment: use lines.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

Answer (score 1):

The following should work, with the gived structure of your lines:

```
with open('so.txt') as f:
    l=f.readlines()

l[-1]=l[-1]+'\n'

with open('so.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[x.find(' ')+1:x.find('pts')]):
        f.write(i)
```

Output:

```
Username5, 43 pts
Username6, 56 pts
Username2, 64 pts
Username1, 78 pts
Username4, 81 pts
Username3, 98 pts
```